# What does it mean "to ride a number"?

Tags: meaning, obscure-terms

This excerpt is from [an article in the New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/09/23/world/middleeast/as-others-flee-to-west-most-syrian-refugees-remain-in-region.html):

> Grown men ride hot-pink numbers, ringing tinny bells to clear their paths, to jobs in the sprawling souk or doing grunt work for aid groups

Could anyone tell me how can a number be ridden? I suppose that a number here is some synonym for a bicycle, but I cannot find any reference of this in a dictionary.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Number" is slang for a thing (woman's dress, car, bicycle, etc) which is in some way exceptional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out definition #3  #11 and #12 in this [Dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/number) entry:

> 3. *informal* An item of clothing of a particular type, regarded with approval or admiration:
>      "Yvonne was wearing a little black number"

These definitions show the usage of *number* as a specific instance of the class of objects under discussion, and specifically one whose style is being discussed. In your example, the stylishness of the bicycles.

Comment: Have I understood this correctly, that this case is similar to the meaning of `one` in similar situations. The author could write `Grown men ride hot-pink ones` ? But `numbers` was used because the style of bicycles is in question.

Comment: Yes, that is how I understand it.